Playwright Test runner struggles with clicking combobox elements and opening option lists. Inconsistent behaviour
Video1: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BYTFZ5O_0dwTKAuS3siqiQseh8LcWYmH/view?usp=drive_link
Video2: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fyBVhQM2brEAdgJQNeRcLRtJNfXGnNMq/view?usp=drive_link
Video3: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DthXDwi6HGg_NDV5LtitkaGocYbaR69Y/view?usp=drive_link
Video 1: There is a weird issue where the runner can't click on the element. This is the error: "subtree intercepts pointer events retrying click action"
so I try .click({force: true}) and it works but then
Video 2:  the next combobox  fails to open the list, however since the actionability checks are disabled there is no retry, it passes that step and stalls at the next. Why does the force api work for one combobox but fails on the next?
Video 3: The behaviour takes another left. If I pause the script and step through the test, the combobox clicks and the list opens passing the next step without a hitch. If I click through manually, again I experience no problems opening up the list of options.
This behaviour has come up in multiple place throughout the app, and ignoring it isn't possible anymore.
I would really appreciate some help diagnosing this problem and figuring out the source of this behaviour.  If i can troubleshoot it, and the problem lies with the our app DOM. Then I can request changes from the developers but I have to understand why this is happening first.
I've tried different solutions locator.dispatchEvent and even locator.evaluate(e => e.click). To no effect. There is no calculated z-index property on any of the relevant elements.
Since it works when I use debugging tools, those are of little help. Is there a way to capture and log the element that receives the event?

Can you share a [mcve] of your code and page under test?

@ggorlen Unfortunately I can't. The product code is proprietary and runs on a local environment. Building a minimal reproducible example of something this complex is far out of my depth as a tester.
